# Serializing Dynamic C# Object as JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. This app includes C#, Razor, and JSON.NET. I have a C# object that looks like this:

```
public class MyBlueprint
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public string Approach { get; set; }

  public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

At this time, I have a list of `MyBlueprint` objects that is something like this:

```
List<MyBlueprint> x = new List<MyBlueprint>();
{
  new MyBlueprint { Name="Bill", Approach="straight", Value=1 },
  new MyBlueprint { Name="Bill", Approach="straight", Value=7 },
  new MyBlueprint { Name="Bill", Approach="straight", Value=10 },
  new MyBlueprint { Name="John", Approach="straight", Value=120 },
  new MyBlueprint { Name="John", Approach="straight", Value=105 },
  new MyBlueprint { Name="John", Approach="straight", Value=150 },
  new MyBlueprint { Name="John", Approach="straight", Value=100 },
  new MyBlueprint { Name="Jill", Approach="curved", Value=1 },
  new MyBlueprint { Name="Jill", Approach="curved", Value=2 },
  new MyBlueprint { Name="Jill", Approach="curved", Value=5 },
  new MyBlueprint { Name="Jill", Approach="curved", Value=8 }
};
```

I need to flatten out the collection of `MyBlueprint` objects into a pre-defined JSON structure. The end goal is to have JSON in my view that looks like this:

```
var results = [
  { "name": "Bill", "approach":"straight", options: { begin: 1, end: 10 } },
  { "name": "John", "approach":"straight", options: { begin: 100, end: 150 } },
  { "name": "Jill", "approach":"curved", options: { chosen: [1, 2, 5, 8] } }
];
```

The `options` parameter has different properties based on the value of `approach`. The JSON above shows two different structures: `curved` and `straight`. I will have more. For that reason, I'm trying to figure out a dynamic approach without creating a ton of model classes. Currently, I have the following:

```
var names = new[] { "Bill", "John", "Jill" };
foreach (var name in names)
{
  var blueprints = x.Where(y => y.Name == name).Select(z => z.Value.ToString());    
}
```

I know how to get the list of `chosen` values for a `curved` set. I know how to get the `begin` and `end` values for a `straight` set. However, I do not know what to do with them once I have them. I'm trying to figure out how to create a dynamic C# object that I can serialize as JSON and put it the view. What am I missing? I feel kind of stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you have to do following thing.

Create class.

```
public class Options
{
    public Options()
    {
    }

    public Options(List<int> d,string approach)
    {
       if (approach == "straight")
       {
          begin = d.Min();
          end = d.Max();
       }
       else if (approach == "curved")
       {
           choosen = d.Select(cc => cc).ToArray();
       }
    }

    public int? begin { get; set; }
    public int? end { get; set; }
    public int[] choosen { get; set; }
}
```

and your linq query

```
 var result = (from item in x
                          group item by new { item.Name, item.Approach } into g
                          select new
                          {
                              name = g.Key.Name,
                              approach = g.Key.Approach,
                              options = new Options(g.Select(cc => Convert.ToInt32(cc.Value)).ToList(), g.Key.Approach)
                          }).ToList();

            string value = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

Comment: Something like this is probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the data structure you're looking for with anonymous types if you are so inclined. Assuming your "blueprints" are stored in `myBluePrints`:

```
var toBeSerialized = myBlueprints
    .GroupBy(bp => new {bp.Name, bp.Approach})
    .Select(bpg => new
    {
        name = bpg.Key.Name,
        approach = bpg.Key.Approach,
        options = new
        {
            begin = bpg.Min(bp => bp.Value),
            end = bpg.Max(bp => bp.Value)
        }
    });
```

That said, I think the easiest way to build this would be to just write a class corresponding to `options`, and a class corresponding to the top level blueprint objects in your array. In other words, the "ton of model classes" (two, specifically) that you're trying to avoid are probably the easiest way to solve this problem.